# Background swipe on click?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 anchor link in a div, Now I want the background toggle should be animated when I click on one.

I want something like radio button swipe.

```js
$('.wrap').find('a').click(function(){
  $('.wrap a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active')
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

.wrap a {
    width: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #4385F5;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4385F5;
    position: relative;
}

.wrap a.active {
    background: #4385F5;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">
        This
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        That
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: your code is working so what you want?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Yes its working but I want something else. Like this - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.wrap').find('a').click(function(){
  $('.wrap a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active')
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

.wrap a {
    width: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #4385F5;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4385F5;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.wrap a.active {
    background: #4385F5;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">
        This
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        That
    </a>
</div>
```

What kind of animation do you want?

If you want animation of fade, try to use `transition`

```css
input[name="radio"]{
  display: none;
}

.wrap{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 110px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

label{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: red;
  z-index: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#radio-1:checked ~ .slide{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 55px;
  height: 40px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 4;
}
#radio-2:checked ~ .slide{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  height: 40px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 4;
  
}
.slide{
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-1" checked/>
  <label for="radio-1">This</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-2"/>
  <label for="radio-2">That</label>
   <span class="slide"></span>

</div>
```

Comment: what changes  you did in your answer? Can you state that?

Comment: @AlivetoDie I added transition in .wrap a

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want blue color should be slide like this -https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

Comment: @YoungKyunJin Yes I want to like this, but  on anchor tag not on radio button